# Add many pictures in many pages of word using VFP

Tags: image, ms-word, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I need a picture to be added on a word document on EVERY SINGLE page of it.

Akwardly my `do while + page break` won't do the job for me.

How can I solve this issue?

Here's my code:

```
DO WHILE .not. eof ()

oShape = oShapes.addPicture ("C:\Cartas\Icons\firma-bgh-5cm.png", 0 -1,100,300,,)  

oWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Select

oWord.Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalPosition = 2
oWord.Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeVerticalPosition = 4
oWord.Selection.ShapeRange.Left= 3.8*72 && Move 4.2 inches x 72 points/inch
oWord.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = pvertical


***SALTO DE PAGINA***
.InsertBreak
*********************

`end do`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the formatting - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I also removed non-constructive comments. Good luck!

Comment: You probably want to be using SCAN ... ENDSCAN instead of DO WHILE !EOF()

Comment: Is the 1 in `oWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Select` representing the page number?

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting the same image on every page, it may be better to set it up as a watermark. This article tells you how to do it in Word: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Insert-a-watermark-or-change-a-watermark-f90f26a5-2101-4a75-bbfe-f27ef05002de

Record a macro as you do it to see how to translate that into Automation code.

Comment: I will try this and come back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, i haven't found an answer to my question. Thanks anyway!